# jQuery mouseover with slideUp

Tags: jquery, slide

When i use this function create for move div up and down with events mouseover and mouseout , all time repeat me the same effect many times :

```
<script>
function groups_cover_fade_on(id)
{
jQuery("."+id).slideDown(1000);
}

function groups_cover_fade_out(id)
{
jQuery("."+id).slideUp(1000);
}
</script>
```

**I have 2 divs :**

```
<div id="container" class="c1" onmouseout="groups_cover_fade_on('c1');">

<div id="container_2" class="c1" onmouseover="groups_cover_fade_out('c1');"></div>

</div>
```

When i go and the event onmouseout execute the script all time repeat other time the same effect 2 o 3 times , and after this stop , i only wish show the div with slide when i go mouseover and hide when mouseout

At the moment i try many things and no get good results

Thank´s , the best regards

Comment: You're missing a closing `"` on the `ID` of your 2nd div.

Comment: Yes but it´s because i writte fast this but the problem it´s the same , thank´s

Comment: That mouseover function will execute once for every time your mouse moves on that div. Use jquery to bind mousenter and mouseleave. http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/ examples are at the bottom of the page

Comment: What do you trying to archive?

Comment: Don´t understand you , archive ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the example with [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and `mouseleave` instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout`.

In [mouseover](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) documentation you can see why you're having this problem:

> This event type can cause many headaches due to event bubbling. For
>   instance, when the mouse pointer moves over the Inner element in this
>   example, a mouseover event will be sent to that, then trickle up to
>   Outer. **This can trigger our bound mouseover handler at inopportune
>   times**. See the discussion for **.mouseenter() for a useful alternative**.

Besides that you're binding event to the class `.c`, which will trigger both div's events when `mouseover` and `mouseout`

You should try instead using the id selector `$('#container')`, like this:

```
$('#container').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).slideUp(1000);
});

$('#container').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).slideDown(1000);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve but here is an example of using mouseenter and mouseleave instead

http://jsfiddle.net/Lyy15nx6/1/

```
$("#container").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).slideUp(1000);
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).slideDown(1000);
});
```

You will see once the slide up is done, it will slide down this is because since the div disappeared, it triggers mouseleave and it slides down again

Comment: But i need inside function , regards

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that and I don't see how my answer is different from the check marked